# Cumulative Homography Wrongly Scaling

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, homography, image-stitching

I'm to build a panorama image of the ground covered by a downward facing camera (at a fixed height, around 1 metre above ground). This could potentially run to thousands of frames, so the Stitcher class' built in `panorama` method isn't really suitable - it's far too slow and memory hungry.

Instead I'm assuming the floor and motion is planar (not unreasonable here) and trying to build up a cumulative homography as I see each frame. That is, for each frame, I calculate the homography from the previous one to the new one. I then get the cumulative homography by multiplying that with the product of all previous homographies.

Let's say I get `H01` between frames 0 and 1, then `H12` between frames 1 and 2. To get the transformation to place frame 2 onto the mosaic, I need to get `H01*H12`. This continues as the frame count increases, such that I get `H01*H12*H23*H34*H45*...`.

In code, this is something akin to:

```
cv::Mat previous, current;

// Init cumulative homography
cv::Mat cumulative_homography = cv::Mat::eye(3);

video_stream >> previous;
for(;;) {

        video_stream >> current;
        // Here I do some checking of the frame, etc

        // Get the homography using my DenseMosaic class (using Farneback to get OF)
        cv::Mat tmp_H = DenseMosaic::get_homography(previous,current);

        // Now normalise the homography by its bottom right corner
        tmp_H /= tmp_H.at<double>(2, 2);

        cumulative_homography *= tmp_H;

        previous = current.clone( );
}
```

It works pretty well, except that as the camera moves "up" in the viewpoint, the homography scale decreases. As it moves down, the scale increases again. This gives my panoramas a perspective type effect that I really don't want.

For example, this is taken on a few seconds of video moving forward then backward. The first frame looks ok:
[image: Frame 2 implanted onto frame 1]

The problem comes as we move forward a few frames:
[image: The homography scales down causing the frame to become smaller on the panorama]

Then when we come back again, you can see the frame gets bigger again:
[image]

I'm at a loss as to where this is coming from.

I'm using Farneback dense optical flow to calculate pixel-pixel correspondences as below (sparse feature matching doesn't work well on this data) and I've checked my flow vectors - they're generally very good, so it's not a tracking problem. I also tried switching the order of the inputs to find homography (in case I'd mixed up the frame numbers), still no better.

```
cv::calcOpticalFlowFarneback(grey_1, grey_2, flow_mat, 0.5, 6,50, 5, 7, 1.5, flags);

// Using the flow_mat optical flow map, populate grid point correspondences between images
std::vector<cv::Point2f> points_1, points_2;
median_motion = DenseMosaic::dense_flow_to_corresp(flow_mat, points_1, points_2);
cv::Mat H = cv::findHomography(cv::Mat(points_2), cv::Mat(points_1), CV_RANSAC, 1);
```

Another thing I thought it could be was the translation I include in the transformation to ensure my panorama is centred within the scene:

```
cv::warpPerspective(init.clone(), warped, translation*homography, init.size());
```

But having checked the values in the homography before the translation is applied, the scaling issue I mention is still present.

Any hints are gratefully received. There's a lot of code I could put in but it seems irrelevant, please do let me know if there's something missing

**UPDATE**
I've tried switching out the `*=` operator for the full multiplication and tried reversing the order the homographies are multiplied in, but no luck. Below is my code for calculating the homography:

```
/**
\brief Calculates the homography between the current and previous frames


*/
cv::Mat DenseMosaic::get_homography()
{

    cv::Mat grey_1, grey_2; // Grayscale versions of frames


    cv::cvtColor(prev, grey_1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::cvtColor(cur, grey_2, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    // Calculate the dense flow
    int flags = cv::OPTFLOW_FARNEBACK_GAUSSIAN;
    if (frame_number > 2) {
        flags = flags | cv::OPTFLOW_USE_INITIAL_FLOW;
    }
    cv::calcOpticalFlowFarneback(grey_1, grey_2, flow_mat, 0.5, 6,50, 5, 7, 1.5, flags);

    // Convert the flow map to point correspondences
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> points_1, points_2;
    median_motion = DenseMosaic::dense_flow_to_corresp(flow_mat, points_1, points_2);

    // Use the correspondences to get the homography
    cv::Mat H = cv::findHomography(cv::Mat(points_2), cv::Mat(points_1), CV_RANSAC, 1);

    return H;
}
```

And this is the function I use to find the correspondences from the flow map:

```
/**
\brief Calculate pixel->pixel correspondences given a map of the optical flow across the image
\param[in]  flow_mat Map of the optical flow across the image
\param[out] points_1 The set of points from #cur
\param[out] points_2 The set of points from #prev
\param[in]  step_size The size of spaces between the grid lines
\return The median motion as a point

Uses a dense flow map (such as that created by cv::calcOpticalFlowFarneback) to obtain a set of point correspondences across a grid.
*/
cv::Point2f DenseMosaic::dense_flow_to_corresp(const cv::Mat &flow_mat, std::vector<cv::Point2f> &points_1, std::vector<cv::Point2f> &points_2, int step_size)
{

    std::vector<double> tx, ty;
    for (int y = 0; y < flow_mat.rows; y += step_size) {
        for (int x = 0; x < flow_mat.cols; x += step_size) {
            /* Flow is basically the delta between left and right points */
            cv::Point2f flow = flow_mat.at<cv::Point2f>(y, x);
            tx.push_back(flow.x);
            ty.push_back(flow.y);


            /*  There's no need to calculate for every single point,
            if there's not much change, just ignore it
            */
            if (fabs(flow.x) < 0.1 && fabs(flow.y) < 0.1)
                continue;

            points_1.push_back(cv::Point2f(x, y));
            points_2.push_back(cv::Point2f(x + flow.x, y + flow.y));
        }
    }

    // I know this should be median, not mean, but it's only used for plotting the 
    // general motion direction so it's unimportant.
    cv::Point2f t_median;
    cv::Scalar mtx = cv::mean(tx);
    t_median.x = mtx[0];
    cv::Scalar mty = cv::mean(ty);
    t_median.y = mty[0];

    return t_median;
}
```

Comment: Something you should definitely check is the source and destination coordinate system of all your transforms. For instance, does `H01` warp frame #1 onto frame #0, or is it the converse ? Depending on this, determine whether the cumulative homography should be `H01*H12*H23*...` or `...*H23*H12*H01`. Also, you might want to avoid the `*=` operator which is more ambiguous than explicit assignment and multiplication (e.g. `H = H*tmp_H`). If the above does not solve your problem, it could be useful to see the code for your `get_homography` function.

Comment: Thanks @AldurDisciple, I tried playing around with the accumulation direction but to no avail - the other way round the reconstruction is wrong and the shrinking still occurs. I'm about to update my answer with the code for homography calculation.

Comment: If the homography computation is good, it could be due to a problem with RANSAC. How many corresponding points do you use? What are the image dimensions and the value of `step_size`?

Comment: Also, did you try running your program with another input video, to check if you observe the same behavior or a different one?

Comment: A last hint, are you aware that there is a function `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` for sparse optical flow, which should be more accurate and efficient than `calcOpticalFlowFarneback` ?

Comment: Hi @AldurDisciple, thanks for your help. The step size is set to 5px on a .3MP image. I'll check how many remain after RANSAC. I have, it's the same problem on other videos. Yup, I have an alternate version of the software running with sparse feature matching, using SURF descriptor matching at keyframes, then tracking KLT features between them to balance speed against accuracy. It's exactly the same problem oddly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was because my viewpoint was close to the features, meaning that the non-planarity of the tracked features was causing skew to the homography. I managed to prevent this (it's more of a hack than a method...) by using `estimateRigidTransform` instead of `findHomography`, as this does not estimate for perspective variations.

In this particular case, it makes sense to do so, as the view does only ever undergo rigid transformations.